# Indentation of preprocessor directives

Tags: indentation

In my `vimrc` I have the following line, which figures all the indentation of my files.

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

When writing C programs sometimes I use preprocessor directives like `#ifdef foo` and `#endif`. When writing one such directive inside a block Vim indents the directive like this.

```
int main()
{
#ifdef foo
...
#endif
}
```

But I would like them to be indented as any other statement, i.e.

```
int main()
{
    #ifdef foo
    ...
    #endif
}
```

`indentkeys` might be able to do the job. From `:help 'indentkeys'`

> A list of keys that, when typed in Insert mode, cause reindenting of
>   the current line.  Only happens if 'indentexpr' isn't empty.

But my `indentexpr` is empty and I have no idea what I should put there; or if there is a better solution.

On the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code) I have read

> If you plan on using file type based indentation, don't set
>   'smartindent' or 'cindent'. You may still set 'autoindent', since it
>   doesn't interfere.

So, since I am using file type based indentation I don't want to use
`smartindent` nor `cindent`.

How can I achieve my intended indentation for preprocessor directives?

Comment: Vim uses cindent for C. See `:help cinoptions-values`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This specific behavior is handled by the [`'cinkeys'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cinkeys%27) option.  `'cinkeys'` is similar to `'indentkeys'` but is only used when `'cindent'` is enabled.

By default, it contains the `0#` setting which causes the leading indentation to be removed when a line starts with `#`.  To disable this, you could add

```
setlocal cinkeys-=0#
```

to `~/.vim/after/indent/c.vim` and `~/.vim/after/indent/cpp.vim`.

Comment: Thank you. This seems seems to work when I write a new directive. But if I try to reindent an old one, say by doing `gg=G`, it leaves the directives unchanged. How could I make it work in both cases?

Comment: @GonçaloRibeiro It can't be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047521/make-vim-indent-c-preprocessor-directives-the-same-as-other-statements